# Javascript onClick function with html table include FORM

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to add **input** form in the cell of table. 
It is easy to use `table`, but I'm confused about using Javascript with `table`.

Is there any tips or help?

Below is my code:

```
<a onClick="newRow()" class="btn btn-primary text-light">Add New</a>

<script>

function newRow(){
var table = document.getElementById("tb_deviceDetail");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "PLACE FOR INPUT FORM";
cell2.innerHTML = "PLACE FOR INPUT FORM";   
}

</script>
```

The input form code is: `input type="text" name="input01"`, but this input form need to be POST to any page with PHP. So it needs a `form method="post" action="#"` before `input`. But with JAVASCRIPT, I can't realistic my idea.

The onClick function is use to add a **input form with name="xxx"**

Note: I'm a junior  coder... please help me!

Comment: You should read [an introductory guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, I am generating inputs dynamically on click and asigning its name (name1,name2,name3...) with counter variable.

and posting it normally using HTML form.

```js
let counter = 0;

    function newRow()
    {
    var table = document.getElementById("tb_deviceDetail");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="input${++counter}">`;
    cell2.innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="input${++counter}">`;   
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    
    <a onClick="newRow()" class="btn btn-primary text-light">Add New</a>

    <form action="#" method="POST" >

        <table id="tb_deviceDetail">
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```